# AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'split'", 'occurred at index 1') for single values in a cell

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Below is my code which I am trying to run -

```
for i in range(1, 65):
    df_ff["Change No_{}".format(i)] = ""


def myfunc(x):

    if x["Change No"] == "All 64":

        for num in range(1,65):
            x["Change No_{}".format(num)] = 'TRUE'

    else:

        all_nums = x["Change No"].split("、")
        for num in all_nums:
            x["Change No_{}".format(num)] = 'TRUE'

    return x
```

The error place is at all_nums = x["Change No"].split("、"). This is only occuring where there is a single value in a cell. So I needed a help to write the condition for single valued cell.

Background - I am reading file for a local **xlsx file** in my program and trying to do some data manipulation but its showing me error as per the title of my question. The data inside the column **Change No** are of **String (All 64 valves)** & **Integer (1-64) format**. The dtype of the **Change No** column is **Object type**.

**Data sample in Change No column -**

> 4、10、11、15、32、36、46、48、58
>
> All 64 valve needles
>
> 1

**Purpose of the code -**

The code will split the data in Change No columns and put respective values to each of the respective headers like 4 should be put under Change No_4 as True value for the first row of the data sample

Comment: tl;dr - Did you try `x["Change No"].str.split("、")`? see [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Comment: @SpghttCd Yes I had tried this one but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Then you should perhaps post `x.head()` or `x["Change No"].head()`

Comment: @SpghttCd I checked doing print(all_nums) it is giving me values in splitted style

Comment: @SpghttCd I got to know why my code is not working. It is working perfectly fine for 1st two lines of data samples (4、10、11、15、32、36、46、48、58; All 64 valve needles) but when it gets to final sample where there is only 1 single value so it cannot split so that is why the code is throwing above error. Could you please help me to write the condition for the last sample in the same function?

Comment: Shouldn't be the problem if `1` is a string. E.g. try `print('asdf'.split('、'))`

Comment: Can you please help me to write the full code because there are many single digit numbers in my data. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I really would like to do that - I still don't get yet what exactly goes wrong in your case, because it sounds as if you would have _different_ datatypes in one single column of your dataframe - which is not recommendable nor really likely if you created it in a regular way... Would you please try `x["Change No"].astype(str).str.split("、")`?

Comment: The main problem is, that you didn't provide a proper [mcve]. Your code is not executable, there is nothing to see where a column called `Change No` is even created, you still did not provide a sample data as suggested (`df.head()`). Sorry, but on this basis it's just guessing.